# Wrap li into another li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below ul list. In which I want to wrap last three li into another ul li tag.

**My html**

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

**I want**

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>
<ul>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**my code**

```
$('ul li:not(:first)').wrap('<li></li>');
```

But it's wraping individual li into another li. pls help

Comment: And your question is ? What is your problem ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need here in this context is [`.wrapAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)

Try,

```
$('ul li:not(:first)').wrapAll('<li><ul></ul></li>');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/8cMan/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

according to me we should avoid :first pseudo class because in many cases this not work so try following code

```
 $(function(){

$('ul li').eq(0).addClass('hi');

$('li').not('.hi').wrapAll('<ul><li></li></ul>');

});
```